# Laravel Eloquent - Why take(n) works but limit(n) doesn't?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

According to laravel docs, take() is just an alias to the limit().

Why doesn't query no 4 doesn't work while other work just fine.

```
1. $employee->take(2)->get();   // Works
2. $employee->limit(2)->get(); // Works
3. $employee->get()->take(2); // Works
4. $employee->get()->limit(2) // Gives Error; Method Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection::limit does not exist.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you call `get`, your database query has been executed, so the result is an `Illuminate\Support\Collection` and when you call `limit` on `Collection` it throws an error because `Collection` class does not have a `limit` function.

`limit` and `take` are both executed on your database query as they are both functions of `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder` and `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder` also, not on the `Collection`.

Notice: the Third statement works because `Illuminate\Support\Collection` has a `take` function also.

Comment: @Tintin Yes both `Eloquent` and `Query Builder` has both `take && limit` functions.

Comment: @Tintin Because `Illuminate\Support\Collection` has a `take` function also :-)

Comment: @ok just went through the documents and it appear  eloquent collection has it's own take method.